# Allow input only 2 decimals (C# + WindowsPhone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, keydown

I am using this code to allow only input 1 decimal point. It runs fine. But how I can do it to allow  input only 2 numbers after decimal point?

C#

```
 private void txtPrecio_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)sender;

        if (txt1.Text.Contains(".") && e.PlatformKeyCode == 190)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the last character is a numeric value, the penultimate character is a numeric value and the character before that is a dot/period.

Or if you wanted to ue a Regex*, something like

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(".[0-9]{2}$", txt1.Text)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

*-This regex was done from memory but it's looking (intended to) to see if the text endswith a decimal place and then 2 numeric characters.

Comment: thanks. I followed your example and I have created this Regex and runs fine: if (Regex.IsMatch( txt1.Text, "^\\d*\\.\\d{2}$")) e.Handled=true;

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24822/Silverlight-Super-TextBox-ComboBox-Masked-TextBox) or some other Silverlight based masked edit could help you solve your problem in a much cleaner fashion?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just format the result:

```
double e = double.Parse(text);
string nText = string.Format("{0:0.##}", e);
e = double.Parse(nText);
```